# Within Pivitoal Cloud Foundary is there a way to set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE per each space?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

For each space within an org using Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) is there a way to set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE for each space?

- space1: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: development
- space2: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: performance
- space3: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: production
- etc...

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: PCF is a polyglot system. That means you can run apps built in multiple languages in PCF. PCF orgs or spaces are logical constructs for user management and deploying apps. They are not runtime constructs. Orgs and Spaces are agnostic.

Comment: That said, by default, in cloud environment, the `cloud` profile is active for Spring based applications. If you need any other profile to be active, it is up to the settings of that application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary way that you would set Spring profiles on Cloud Foundry is via environment variables.

Cloud Foundry does not provide a way to set environment variable groups per org or space. You can only set a staging and a running environment variable group which applies to all staging or all running apps. That's in addition to the standard facilities for setting environment variables on an application.

---

I think you might be able to get this to work, but it'll take a little effort. Here's the idea.

1. Create a custom buildpack (don't panic, this isn't that difficult). The buildpack's only responsibility would be to create a `.profile.d/` script (just a regular Bash script) that contains `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=<some-profile>`.

   Any buildpack can create `.profile.d/` scripts which are primarily used to configure environment variables. These scripts are automatically sourced by the environment before any application starts. Thus if the buildpack sets `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` here, it would be available to your app and take effect.

   https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html#contract

   You would just need to create the `bin/supply` and `bin/detect` scripts as defined at the link below. The `bin/supply` is where you'd put your logic to create the `.profile.d/` script and `bin/detect` could be as simple as `exit 0` which would just tell it to run always.

   https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/understand-buildpacks.html#buildpack-scripts
2. Your custom buildpack could be as simple as hard coding profiles to use or it could be fancy and look at the `VCAP_APPLICATION` environment which contains the space name.

   Ex: `echo $VCAP_APPLICATION | jq .space_name`.

   The buildpack could then apply logic to set the correct profile given the space name. I don't think the org name is available to the app at staging/runtime, at least not through environment variables, so it would be harder to apply logic based on that.
3. The last step is using CF's multi-buildpack support. Your custom buildpack would be a supply buildpack so it would be first, then you'd list the actual buildpack to use second as you push your application.

   Ex: `cf push -b https://github.com/your-profile/your-custom-buildpack -b java_buildpack your-cool-app`.

   https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess we can also create an `user-provided-service` with `spring.profile.active` stuff and have that service bound to the Apps when it is being pushed

Comment: @Arun That's an option, but it requires developer interaction to make it work, so it's really not that much different than setting an env variable for each app.